# Select ng-repeat checkbox Selenium

Tags: angularjs, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have my ng-repeat checkbox selection :

```
<label> <input style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 5px"
               type="checkbox" 
               ng-model="entity.checked"
               ng-change="getEntityFromModal(entity.val, entity.checked)" /> <span>{{entity.val}}</span>
</label>
```

I'm trying to locate a checkbox represented by the label `01` with this:

```
multiCheckBoxXPath = "//input(@ng-model='entity.checked')/label[contains(text(),'" +value.substring(0, 2) +"')]";
```

Where value is an elongated `string` version of what is displayed beside checkbox.  First two letters are displayed.

I'm locating it via the label using a `[contains(text())` then using the assigned `ng-model` to try and select the corresponding checkbox.

Unfortunately I'm getting -

`Unable to find //input(@ng-model='entity.checked')/label[contains(text(),'01')]`

I'm a bit stuck here so any ideas appreciated.

Comment: why is closing bracket `)]` missing in your error message ... just a typo, or are they really not there ???

Comment: hi as per the source code your path should contain @ng-model='entity.checked' not @ng-model='depot.checked'

Comment: Again, apologies was a typo - I have two identical checkbox list, I must have been confused when copying over.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this xpath

```
"//span[contains(text(),'" +value.substring(0, 2) +"')]/preceding-sibling::input"
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: preceding-sibling!! thanks a million works an absolute charm :)

Answer (score 1):

You can further filter your xpath to find exact checkbox element if there is multiple `input` element

```
String xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'" +value.substring(0, 2) +"')]/preceding-sibling::input[@type = 'checkbox']"
```